# Nhibernate Fluent datetime mapping creates null column in DB

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, fluent

I really struggle to find an answer anywhere.

I got this class declaration:

```
public class Order
{
   public virtual long Id { get; set; }

   public virtual DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a mapping class where I map the property `OrderDate` using the following:

```
Map(x => x.OrderDate)
    .CustomSqlType("datetime2")
    .Not.Nullable();
```

When it is exported to the database it creates NULL column, ignoring Not.Nullable instruction.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, that the mapping should be like this:

```
Map(x => x.OrderDate)
    .CustomType("datetime2") // not CustomSqlType
    .Not.Nullable();
```

Expecting that you are using SQL Server 2008+, check this link for more info about relationship DB., CLR and NHibernate types [NHibernate and Ms Sql Server 2008: Date, Time, DateTime2 and DateTimeOffset](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/11/nhibernate-and-ms-sql-server-2008-date-time-datetime2-and-datetimeoffset.aspx)